# Angular Material Design Datepicker leads to Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, angular, angular-material, datepicker, timestamp

When I use the Material Design date picker in my Angular code, to set a date, which I then send to my REST server with a MySQL database and a TIMESTAMP column, I get the error message: "Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect date time value:"

The reason for this is, that the date picker exports the date in the following date format ("2022-02-23T23:00:00.000Z"), while MySQL expects a date format like this: "2022-02-17 12:55:31".

How can I configure the date picker to export the date in the correct MySQL format? I know that there are ways to configure the MySQL server to accept this special format, but I'd prefer to do it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), you can manipulate dates easily.

```
const formatedDate = moment(yourDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```